# Passing a value from PhantomJS to node.js

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I have a phantomJS script that is executed via an [`exec()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) call in a node.js script. 
Now I need to return a string from the PhantomJS script so that it can be utilized back in node.
Is there a way to achieve that ?

**Node app:**

```
child = exec('./phantomjs dumper.js',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout, stderr);      // Always empty
    });
```

**dumper.js (Phantom)**

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open( system.args[1], function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access the network!');
    } else {

        return "String"; // Doesn't work
    }
    phantom.exit('String2'); //Doesn't work either
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah just output a JSON string from PhantomJS using `JSON.stringify(result)` and parse it in node.js with `JSON.parse(stdout)`.

Like this for example:

**Node.js:**

```
child = exec('./phantomjs dumper.js',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout, stderr);      // Always empty
        var result = JSON.parse(stdout);
    }
);
```

**PhantomJS:**

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open( system.args[1], function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access the network!');
    } else {

        console.log(JSON.stringify({string:"This is a string", more: []}));
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

[Here is some boilerplate](https://gist.github.com/3112441) for how to use PhantomJS to scrape.

Comment: Thanks, though where should i put the JSON.stringify('result') call ? after a return statment or as parameter of the exit method (Just tried both and doesn't seem to be working for me)

Comment: You actually don't need to use JSON if you just want to pass a string. I recommended you use JSON because you may want to do more. If you are using PhantomJS to scrap data you could want to share  lot of stuff.

Comment: ok thanks again, that indeed works, what confused me is that comming form the browser side, i expected console.log to only be a way to dump informative data rather a way to actually return stuff..

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler way (if you have the option) is to use the NPM module [phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) instead of [phantomjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs). This allows you to access the browser directly in nodejs instead of maintaining separate scripts.