# Return a value from phantomjs to nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, cheerio

I'm using phantomjs using jquerygo library and am trying to this.

1. Visit a url
2. Click on a link and wait for it to load
3. Grab a particular tag and return it to nodejs for processing.

I realize that in phantomjs:

> The execution is sandboxed, the web page has no access to the phantom object and it can't probe its own setting

But I should be able to return a simple string from the evaluate right?
But that is not working. My code is as follows:

```
var photogsScrapeCount = function(url, callback){
console.log("LOADED PHOTOGSSCRAPE Count");
url = decodeURIComponent(url);
//$.config.site = 'https://www.magnumphotos.com/';
$.config.addJQuery = false;
$.visit(url, function() {
    $.waitForElement(".7n7np102",function() {
        $.getPage(function(page) {
            var imgCounterMinus = page.evaluate(function(){
            $(".7n7np102 a").click(); // open the image enlarge
            var temp = setTimeout(function(){
                imgCounterMinus1 = $("span[id$='TotalPageCount_Lbl']").html();
                imgCounterMinus1 = imgCounterMinus1.split(" ");
                imgCounterMinus1 = imgCounterMinus1[2];
                imgCounterMinus1 = parseInt(imgCounterMinus1);
                console.log("imgCounterMinus1" + imgCounterMinus1);
                return (imgCounterMinus1 - 3);
            }, 4000);
            return temp;
            }); 
            //console.log("After evaluate: " + imgCounterMinus)
        });
    });
});
};
```

Can this be achieved in any different way? The basic example from website is working so I am assuming that the setTimeout is giving me problems. 
Any ideas or suggestions would be very helpful as I have very little experience in writing jquery, Js.

Comment: I used additional return statements during debug. So please ignore them. I have already checked the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979723/passing-a-value-from-phantomjs-to-node-js

Answer (score 0):

The [docs say](https://github.com/travist/jquery.go.js#another-jquery-wrapper-in-nodejs) (emphasis mine):

> For one, this library is not a complete API mirror of jQuery. Every API is **asynchronous (due to its interaction with Phantom.js)**, so there are some differences.

There is also an example how `page.evaluate()` must be used. The result is not returned, but passed into a second callback. There is no way to return something from an asynchronous execution of a function except by using the callback. So the `setTimeout` syntax is also wrong.

```
$(".7n7np102 a").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.getPage(function(page) {
            page.evaluate(function(){
                var imgCounterMinus1 = $("span[id$='TotalPageCount_Lbl']").html();
                imgCounterMinus1 = imgCounterMinus1.split(" ");
                imgCounterMinus1 = imgCounterMinus1[2];
                imgCounterMinus1 = parseInt(imgCounterMinus1);
                console.log("imgCounterMinus1" + imgCounterMinus1);
                return (imgCounterMinus1 - 3);
            }, function(err, result){
                console.log("After evaluate: " + result);
                callback();
                $.close();
            });
        });
    }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: Can you suggest any other approach of doing this?

Comment: I am able to solve the problem of calling the functions in order. Thanks to you. But still I am unable to access the result as it says as undefined.

Comment: I don't know why that would be the case. What PhantomJS version do you use?